# Add a text on CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have generated a circle with `CAShapeLayer` and now trying to add a label on it as follows via `CATextLayer`, but it does not show up. I wonder what I am missing?

```
CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[circleLayer setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(carouselView.frame.size.width - 42, addCardButton.frame.origin.y - 5, 20, 20)] CGPath]];
[circleLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
[circleLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];

CATextLayer* text = [CATextLayer new];
text.string =  @"1";
text.fontSize = 25;
text.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,60,60);
text.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(circleLayer.frame) ,CGRectGetMidY(circleLayer.frame) );
CGFloat vert = CGRectGetMidY(circleLayer.frame) / CGRectGetHeight(text.frame);
text.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, vert );
text.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
text.foregroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];

[circleLayer addSublayer:text];
[[carouselView layer] addSublayer:circleLayer];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing missing actually, the only problem is with the layers' frames. When you set up the circle layer, you don't provide a frame and `bezierPathWithOvalInRect:` doesn't do this. So its frame is still `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`, which means that the text layer is also at position `(0.0, 0.0)` (because you set its frame to `(0,0,60,60)`). Therefore the text layer is in the top left corner of the screen and you might not observe it because it's covered by something else (I don't know how your view hierarchy looks like). Setting the circle layer's frame properly should solve the problem.